# Mergin plugin options

Tags: qgis, heat-map, mergin-maps

Can I use the points created from field study via free **Input App** on Iphone, and Synchronize them into free QGIS, and then use these points in creating a heatmap on QGIS?

Comment: The short answer is yes.  What have you tried so far?  Is there a problem with what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

[Mergin Maps](https://merginmaps.com) Input App can be used on iPhone, install it via [AppStore](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/input/id1478603559). You can use [Mergin Maps QGIS Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/Mergin/) to synchronise the data back to QGIS and create a heatmap.